# how frequency affects performance

Tags: frequency

Can we use 60 Hz induction motor in 50 Hz Current Supply,
What are the possible failures can happen if we use the motor continuously under this circumstances.

Comment: You mean, besides running at the wrong speed?

Comment: yes other than RPM

Comment: A lot of induction motors are specified for 50 or 60 Hz. If this motor is really specified for 60 Hz only, it may overheat due to over-current at 50 Hz. Do you have an exact make/model of motor, or a picture of the nameplate? Link? Anything? What is the rated Voltage of the motor, and what Voltage do you plan to operate it at?

Comment: its 220-240V and 4 amps current 900watts power but its 60Hz motor and using at 50Hz region.

Answer (score 1):

If you operate the motor at 5/6 of the 60 Hz rated voltage, the motor can be operated continuously at rated torque. The operating speed will be 5/6 of the rated 60 Hz speed and the power delivered will be 5/6 of the rated 60 Hz power. The efficiency, power factor, current and temperature rise will not change very much. The life expectancy will not change very much. The self-cooling capability will be reduced slightly because the rotor fins or shaft-mounted fan will be turning at 5/6 the 60 Hz speed. However, the iron losses will also be reduced due to the reduced frequency and the friction and windage losses will be reduced.

If you don't operate the motor at the proper voltage i.e. 5/6 of rated 60 Hz voltage, the effect will be the same as operating any other motor at the wrong voltage.

Re Comment

The proper 50 Hz voltage for a 220-240V, 60 Hz motor would be 183-200V. A supply that is nominally 220V would be 10-20% high for that motor. Below is a graph showing the major effects.

[image]
Image by Ed Cowern